# Unable to connect to the database. Retrying

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to connect to the database, seems like the set-up is correct, but for some reason, it says that it is not available.

`app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common"
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { ConfigModule } from "../config";
import { CreatorModule } from "./creator.module";

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/snaptoon', {
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
        }),
        CreatorModule,
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: []
})

export class AppModule {}
```

The error is: `ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...`

I'm using `'@nestjs/mongoose': '9.0.2'`

Comment: Have you been able to connect to the database from CLI?

Comment: Considered using forRootAsync: `MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: () => ({
                uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/snaptoon',
            }),
        }),`

Comment: There are 10 retries that the connection goes through by default. After the tenth, the full error is printed out. Most likely, your version of mongo does not support one or more of the options you are passing

Comment: In my case, I removed `useCreateIndex:true` and it connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved by updating manually mongoose version to 6.2.2

```
 WARN @nestjs/mongoose@9.0.2 requires a peer of mongoose@^6.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I realize due to this error on npm install

just use:

```
 npm install mongoose@6.2.2 --save
```

Answer (score 37):

Use `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/snaptoon` instead of `mongodb://localhost:27017/snaptoon` as connection string. It worked for me.

Comment: For whoever curious, this is due to Node is now prefer IPv6 which translates localhost to ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 8):

Worked for me when I've added "directConnection=true" to the connection string.

"If set to true, the driver will only connect to the host provided in the URI and will not discover other hosts in the cluster. Direct connections are not valid if multiple hosts are specified."

Before:

```js
MongooseModule.forRoot(
  `mongodb://${host}:${port}/${dbName}`,
),
```

After:

```js
MongooseModule.forRoot(
  `mongodb://${host}:${port}/${dbName}?directConnection=true`,
),
```

My application was working fine in `"@nestjs/mongoose": "^8.0.0"` and I faced this error when I changed to `"@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.0"`.

Docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/connection/#connection-options

Comment: That this change has not been promoted more heavily in the documentation, is beyond me. Thanks for saving us some time here, buddy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to connect with remote database.
I've solved this problem with this adding this 2 query parameter

`?authSource=admin&directConnection=true`

Full URI

`mongodb://username:password@host:port/dbname?authSource=admin&directConnection=true`

And if you get this error

`MongoParseError: Password contains unescaped characters`

wrap your password with `encodeURIComponent` function.

`mongodb://username:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@host:port/dbname?authSource=admin&directConnection=true`

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Node 17 or above? Node now prefers IPv6 over IPv4 from Node 17 so `localhost` will translate to `::1:` and not `127.0.0.1` - [related issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40537). Your local MongoDB server is probably running on `127.0.0.1` and thus your application is unable to connect. Try connecting to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/snaptoon` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73537289/5863472) suggested.

Answer (score 2):

For those people who cannot solve this problem by the answer above, according to the new specs of `nestjs/mongoose`.

It might be solved by deleting the line: `useNewUrlParser: true`.

For me, it works in both ways.

Comment: Mongose 6 are no longer to support the options:  useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex. Cause useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify is false. 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#the-aspromise-method-for-connections
credits to @Alex G

Answer (score 0):

I changed `useCreateIndex: true` to `useCreateIndex: undefined` in `MongooseModule.forRoot()` config parameter object.

Answer (score 0):

had an issue with MongoDB docker image version, solved problem with 3.6 version

Answer (score 0):

1. Database Deployments /Cluster connect : Example: `mongodb+srv://<DataBaseName>:<password>@<clusterName>.gsr9ucc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
2. Turn off all vpn and proxy. In browser and window. Anywhere.
3. Go to mongodb/Network Access set current ip. Check several times to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am using latest version (current date is 04/05/2023) and solved this issue. Some of this step is optional but good to try!

1. Open terminal and make sure MongoDB is running **net start MongoDB**
2. Make sure your connection is success by test connection in MongoDB Compass

note: this code below will generate database (or just make new collection, if the db is already exist) automatically in your mongoDB.

***Nest Js code***

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { CatModule } from './cat/cat.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nest', {
      useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
    }),
    CatModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

cat.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatController } from './cat.controller';
import { CatService } from './cat.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Cat, CatSchema } from './cat.model';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Cat.name, schema: CatSchema },
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [CatController],
  providers: [CatService]
})
export class CatModule { }
```

cat.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection, InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Cat, CatDocument } from './cat.model';
import { Connection, Model } from 'mongoose';
import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CatService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Cat.name) private catModel: Model<CatDocument>) { }
}
```

cat.model.ts

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
    @Prop()
    id: number;

    @Prop()
    name: string;

    @Prop()
    health: string;
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Comment: update & note:
1. I solved the issue after adding useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, and my nestJs could connect to mongodb
2. after that i tried removing  useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, but still working

i didnt know what just happened, but it solved the issue. please correct my answer or comment If you have better explanation.